# How to have a nuxtui date input produce an ISO date string?

Tags: nuxt.js, prisma, zod

I have a nuxt application that uses prisma to save records in a mysql database.

in the prisma schema I have

```
 memberSince DateTime  @db.Date
```

that matches a colum of type DATETIME in mysql

in the frontend form I have

```
<UFormGroup class="" label="Membre depuis" name="memberSince">
    <UInput v-model="state.memberSince" type="date" />
 </UFormGroup>
```

and, using zod,

```
const schema = z.object({
    ...
    memberSince: z.coerce.date(),
}
```

the submit function is as follows

```
async function onSubmit(event: FormSubmitEvent<any>) {
  console.log(schema.safeParse(event.data));
  personsStore.addPerson(toRaw(event.data))
}
```

The console display this

> Object {  ....., memberSince: "2023-12-08", .....} the dots being
> placeholders for other properties

The backend complains saying that memberSince should be an ISO-8601 string.
I have been fighting for hours but I did find how to get or make this iso string.
I need some help.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found this solution. Maybe it is not the best but it works!

```
import {PrismaClient} from "@prisma/client"
const prisma = new PrismaClient()
export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  const body = await readBody(event)
  
  console.log('in backend create person')
  let  persons
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////
  let memberSince =new Date(body.memberSince)

  await prisma.person.create({
    
    data:{
      firstName: body.firstName,
      lastName: body.lastName,
      email: body.email,
      phone: body.phone,
      ///////////////////////////////////////////////////
      memberSince: memberSince,

      memberLastYear: body.memberLastYear
    }
    
  }).then(async ()=>{
      await prisma.person.findMany()
      .then((response) =>{
        persons=response
      })
    })
   
    .catch((error)=>{
      console.log(error.message)
      return {"error":"there was an error"}
    })
  
    return{ persons}
})
```

The lines involved in the solution are the lines under the slashed lines

In addition, the model must use string instead of Date

```
type person ={
  ...
  memberSince: string,
  ....
}
const state person = reactive({
    ...
    memberSince: '',
    ....
})
```